# scrollablePlotArea and drilldown button position

Tags: angular, highcharts, .net-core, scrollable, drilldown

When I click on the bar of the chart, back button to return to the previous level appears in the upper left corner, which if there are many elements disappears from the view when moving the
horizontal scroll, I need that the button can be fixed in the same corner of the chart widget.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLdfl.png)

Please check my demo with the same bug when you click a bar in the chart = >
https://jsfiddle.net/x7w09u6j/1/

```js
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
       scrollablePlotArea: {
        minWidth: 1400,
        scrollPositionX: 0,
      },
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2018'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://statcounter.com" target="_blank">statcounter.com</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },

    series: [
        {
            name: "Browsers",
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [
                {
                    name: "Chrome",
                    y: 62.74,
                    drilldown: "Chrome"
                },
                {
                    name: "Firefox",
                    y: 10.57,
                    drilldown: "Firefox"
                },
                {
                    name: "Internet Explorer",
                    y: 7.23,
                    drilldown: "Internet Explorer"
                },
                {
                    name: "Safari",
                    y: 5.58,
                    drilldown: "Safari"
                },
                {
                    name: "Edge",
                    y: 4.02,
                    drilldown: "Edge"
                },
                {
                    name: "Opera",
                    y: 1.92,
                    drilldown: "Opera"
                },
                {
                    name: "Other",
                    y: 7.62,
                    drilldown: null
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    drilldown: {
           drillUpButton: {
        relativeTo: "spacingBox",
        position: {
          y: 0,
          x: 0,
          align: "left"
        },
      },
        series: [
            {
                name: "Chrome",
                id: "Chrome",
                data: [
                    [
                        "v65.0",
                        0.1
                    ],
                    [
                        "v64.0",
                        1.3
                    ],
                    [
                        "v63.0",
                        53.02
                    ],
                    [
                        "v62.0",
                        1.4
                    ],
                    [
                        "v61.0",
                        0.88
                    ],
                    [
                        "v60.0",
                        0.56
                    ],
                    [
                        "v59.0",
                        0.45
                    ],
                    [
                        "v58.0",
                        0.49
                    ],
                    [
                        "v57.0",
                        0.32
                    ],
                    [
                        "v56.0",
                        0.29
                    ],
                    [
                        "v55.0",
                        0.79
                    ],
                    [
                        "v54.0",
                        0.18
                    ],
                    [
                        "v51.0",
                        0.13
                    ],
                    [
                        "v49.0",
                        2.16
                    ],
                    [
                        "v48.0",
                        0.13
                    ],
                    [
                        "v47.0",
                        0.11
                    ],
                    [
                        "v43.0",
                        0.17
                    ],
                    [
                        "v29.0",
                        0.26
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Firefox",
                id: "Firefox",
                data: [
                    [
                        "v58.0",
                        1.02
                    ],
                    [
                        "v57.0",
                        7.36
                    ],
                    [
                        "v56.0",
                        0.35
                    ],
                    [
                        "v55.0",
                        0.11
                    ],
                    [
                        "v54.0",
                        0.1
                    ],
                    [
                        "v52.0",
                        0.95
                    ],
                    [
                        "v51.0",
                        0.15
                    ],
                    [
                        "v50.0",
                        0.1
                    ],
                    [
                        "v48.0",
                        0.31
                    ],
                    [
                        "v47.0",
                        0.12
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Internet Explorer",
                id: "Internet Explorer",
                data: [
                    [
                        "v11.0",
                        6.2
                    ],
                    [
                        "v10.0",
                        0.29
                    ],
                    [
                        "v9.0",
                        0.27
                    ],
                    [
                        "v8.0",
                        0.47
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Safari",
                id: "Safari",
                data: [
                    [
                        "v11.0",
                        3.39
                    ],
                    [
                        "v10.1",
                        0.96
                    ],
                    [
                        "v10.0",
                        0.36
                    ],
                    [
                        "v9.1",
                        0.54
                    ],
                    [
                        "v9.0",
                        0.13
                    ],
                    [
                        "v5.1",
                        0.2
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Edge",
                id: "Edge",
                data: [
                    [
                        "v16",
                        2.6
                    ],
                    [
                        "v15",
                        0.92
                    ],
                    [
                        "v14",
                        0.4
                    ],
                    [
                        "v13",
                        0.1
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Opera",
                id: "Opera",
                data: [
                    [
                        "v50.0",
                        0.96
                    ],
                    [
                        "v49.0",
                        0.82
                    ],
                    [
                        "v12.1",
                        0.14
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

I'm working with the following versions of HC => "highcharts": "^7.0.3" &
"highcharts-angular": "^2.4.0" (angular 7 +.net core development)

This bug happens in Chrome, Safari in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can bee resolved easily by adding `'.highcharts-drillup-button'` class to fixedSelectors in the ScrollablePlotArea `moveFixedElements` method. Also, this method has to be invoked when the drill-up button is shown. Check code and demo posted below.

**Code:**

```
(function(H) {
  H.Chart.prototype.moveFixedElements = function() {
    var container = this.container,
      fixedRenderer = this.fixedRenderer,
      fixedSelectors = [
        '.highcharts-contextbutton',
        '.highcharts-credits',
        '.highcharts-legend',
        '.highcharts-reset-zoom',
        '.highcharts-subtitle',
        '.highcharts-drillup-button', // button class added here
        '.highcharts-title',
        '.highcharts-legend-checkbox'
      ],
      axisClass;
    if (this.scrollablePixelsX && !this.inverted) {
      axisClass = '.highcharts-yaxis';
    } else if (this.scrollablePixelsX && this.inverted) {
      axisClass = '.highcharts-xaxis';
    } else if (this.scrollablePixelsY && !this.inverted) {
      axisClass = '.highcharts-xaxis';
    } else if (this.scrollablePixelsY && this.inverted) {
      axisClass = '.highcharts-yaxis';
    }
    fixedSelectors.push(axisClass, axisClass + '-labels');
    fixedSelectors.forEach(function(className) {
      [].forEach.call(container.querySelectorAll(className), function(elem) {
        (elem.namespaceURI === fixedRenderer.SVG_NS ?
          fixedRenderer.box :
          fixedRenderer.box.parentNode).appendChild(elem);
        elem.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
      });
    });
  }

  H.Chart.prototype.showDrillUpButton = function() {
    var chart = this,
      backText = this.getDrilldownBackText(),
      buttonOptions = chart.options.drilldown.drillUpButton,
      attr, states;
    if (!this.drillUpButton) {
      attr = buttonOptions.theme;
      states = attr && attr.states;
      this.drillUpButton = this.renderer.button(backText, null, null, function() {
          chart.drillUp();
        }, attr, states && states.hover, states && states.select)
        .addClass('highcharts-drillup-button')
        .attr({
          align: buttonOptions.position.align,
          zIndex: 7
        })
        .add()
        .align(buttonOptions.position, false, buttonOptions.relativeTo || 'plotBox');
    } else {
      this.drillUpButton.attr({
          text: backText
        })
        .align();
    }

    H.Chart.prototype.moveFixedElements.call(this); // invoked to make the button position fixed
  };
})(Highcharts);
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mhvd2ugz/